# SQL Server 2016 issue with WAS 6.1

Tags: sql-server, websphere

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2016 with Websphere 6.1, but I'm unable to do so.

I am getting the error:

> The SQL Version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later.

Comment: Try to use a recent SQLServer jdbc driver


https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Comment: already tried but the same error has occurred

Comment: do you tried with JTDS? https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/

Comment: yes, the issue is not resolved